# Is there an easy way to use JasperReports from Clojure?

Tags: clojure, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I see there is a [Scala wrapper for JasperReports](https://github.com/active-group/ScalaJasper), and I found a [Clojure library for Scala interoperability](https://t6.github.io/from-scala/), as well as [a snippet](https://www.refheap.com/6029) of example code by a beginner [from this discussion](http://clojure-log.n01se.net/date/2012-10-22.html) but I can't find any libraries or working example code for Jasper or DynamicJasper. I thought I had previously found a library or article. Any hints?

The problem is that the JasperReports API is incredibly messy (mutation-focused), so I don't want to write wrapper code from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a thorough tutorial but some pointers on how I've been using JasperReports with JRxml files and Clojure. I have no idea about DynamicJasper.

Here's some stuff you'll need to import.

```
(ns app.reports
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.string :as s])
  (:import [net.sf.jasperreports.engine
            JasperCompileManager
            JasperFillManager
            JasperPrint
            JasperExportManager
            JREmptyDataSource
            JRExporter
            JRException]))
```

Compile your jrxml file:

```
(def my-report
  (JasperCompileManager/compileReport
    (io/input-stream
      (io/file "my-report.jrxml"))))
```

Use a Java `HashMap` with the data / columns you'll pass in to your report to fill it.

```
(def report-data
  (java.util.HashMap. {"attrname_1" "Attr 1 String"
                       "attrname_2" "More data..."}))
```

Fill your report with data from a source:

```
(def filled-report
  (JasperFillManager/fillReport my-report report-data (JREmptyDataSource.)
```

Export your report. Here's how to do it as a PDF.

```
(JasperExportManager/exportReportToPdfFile filled-report "result.pdf")
```

I hope this helps you get started.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out! I started putting together a wrapper lib actually. You're most welcome to contribute or use it:
https://github.com/sventechie/jasper-reports-clj